# Efficient way of removing hundreds of inset hexagons

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I have a model with a LOT of hexagonal shapes extruded into the main body. My goal is to remove all of those hexagons and be left with a relatively smooth surface so that it will make 3D printing less complicated.

[image: Overall model with many inset hexagons]

The best workflow I have come up with is to select the faces manually, and remove them, followed by fixing holes. I have lot of experience in Fusion 360, but I'm quite new to Blender. Is there a more efficient way to select just the inset faces and the walls to remove them, or am I stuck manually selecting thousands of faces?

Here is a closeup of the surfaces I am removing. I have circled one of the holes I patched up. I know it won't follow the curvature of the overall model, but that's okay. The goal is to eliminate overhang and thus the need for support.

[image: Closeup of inset hexagon]

Comment: If you remove the whole area may be you can replace it with the grid fill tool. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#grid-fill

Comment: In the end do you want a clean mesh with the same look or just a smooth area?

Comment: @ArthurBlaquart Just a smooth area. What I get when I fill the hole like in my example is totally fine for printing.

Comment: Ok, it's a bit tricky then, depending on how much accuracy you can it might be best to just remodel it from scratch with a shrinkwrap modifier, or just manually adjust each face. I can't think of any tool that would do the job. perhaps try a decimate modifier and see what you get...